# GridView sorting with ImageButtons and Delete Command not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView control which has 5 bound fields that are sort enabled and 4 template fields. One of the template fields is the Delete Image button that deletes the row when clicked. Now, all is well when users just used the gridview as it is, without sorting. But when they sort it and then press delete, the command argument receives the wrong row information and deletes it instead of deleting what they chose to delete. This happens only with the 2 template fields that have an image button control.

```
<Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AccountNo" HeaderText="Account No" 
            SortExpression="AccountNo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
            SortExpression="Address" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" 
            SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Zip" HeaderText="Zip" SortExpression="Zip" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Utility" HeaderText="Utility" 
            SortExpression="Utility" />                
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="EditLink"  ToolTip="Edit Account" NavigateUrl='<%# GetEditURL(((BillingEntity)Container.DataItem).Id) %>' >
                    <img src="../img/edit.png" border="0"/>
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enable/Disable" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="DisableButton" ImageUrl = "../img/delete.png" ToolTip="Disable Account" CommandName="Disable_Account" CommandArgument='<%#((BillingEntity)Container.DataItem).Id %>' OnClientClick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to disable this account?')==false) {return false;}" Visible='<%# ShowDisableButton(((BillingEntity)Container.DataItem).Status)%>'/>
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="EnableButton" ImageUrl = "../img/add.png" ToolTip="Enable Account" CommandName="Enable_Account" CommandArgument='<%#((BillingEntity)Container.DataItem).Id %>'   Visible='<%# ShowEnableButton(((BillingEntity)Container.DataItem).Status)%>'/>                    
            </ItemTemplate>                
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="Delete" ImageUrl = "../img/cross.png" ToolTip="Delete Account" CommandName="Delete_Account" CommandArgument='<%#((BillingEntity)Container.DataItem).Id %>' OnClientClick="if (confirm('Invoices associated with this account will be deleted permanently. Are you sure you want to delete this account?')==false) {return false;}" />
            </ItemTemplate>                
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>            
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Invoices" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="ViewInvoiceLink" ToolTip="Recent invoices" NavigateUrl='<%# GetViewInvoiceURL(((BillingEntity)Container.DataItem).Id) %>' >
                    <img src="../img/go.png" border="0"/>
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>            
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Submit Invoice" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="InvoiceLink"  ToolTip="Submit invoice" NavigateUrl='<%# GetSubmitInvoiceURL(((BillingEntity)Container.DataItem).Id) %>' >
                    <img src="../img/go.png" border="0"/>
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

**EDIT-Data Source Code**

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetAllEntities" 
    TypeName="DataAccessLayer.Repository.BillingEntityRepository">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="-1" Name="clientId" 
            QueryStringField="clientId" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Name" Name="sortColumn" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="ASC" Name="sortOrder" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

And my GridView Sort method is as follows:

```
protected void GridView_BillingEntity_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    if (ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters.Count == 3)
    {
        ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters[1].DefaultValue = e.SortExpression.ToString();
        ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters[2].DefaultValue = GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);

        GridView_BillingEntity.DataBind();

        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT-Rows as seen by the user**

[image: This is how the user sees a row on the browser. Clicking the delete button will delete the row and refresh the grid.]

Comment: In your _Sorting event, what are you binding the Gridview to? I can't see a DataSource being set.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse: I have edited my post to include the DataSource.

Comment: You said "what they chose to delete"? How do they choose a row ? is there any select button or any other way ?

Comment: @FlopScientist: Added an image to show how the user can choose to delete a row. In this example, I have one row. When there are multiple rows and I sort based on one of the first 6 columns and hit delete on a row. A random row different from the one I choose gets deleted.

Comment: What happens if you display the Command Argument of the ImageButton that does the delete in a label in the same cell? Does it keep the right value when you sort? I have never seen a GridView bound as you have done it. I always use a DataSet - keep it in ViewState if it's not too big and change the SortOrder of the DataSet before databinding on each sort.

Comment: Possibly there may be some slight miss in the code where you check the "CommandName" to take the appropriate action such as:"Delete_Account"

Comment: @MartinSmellworse:Yes, interestingly the sort maintains the CommandArgument Value. But when I debug through my handler code after pressing delete, the command argument that gets passed is not what is in the label!

Comment: To be precise. It is the same as the command argument value that was in that row before sorting.

Comment: Sounds to me like you might be binding the grid twice. Once every time you postback and once when you sort. If your delete is taking place between those two databinds, it would explain why it picks up the 'last' ID. Edit. I see someone else has made the same suggestion already.

Answer (score 1):

On clicking the Delete button, Page Load occurs before your Delete handler code. So if you bind the `GridView` in the `page_load` event, You should bind under a `!IsPostBack` condition:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = MyDataSource;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Because if you bind the `GridView` every time , data will be loaded afresh, i.e  the `GridView` is repopulated with unsorted data, thereby losing the previous sort order.